# 要素を左の端からはみ出して表示させたい。

Tags: html, css

お世話になります。

要素を左の端からはみ出して表示させたいです。
下のコードのように親要素に
`overflow:visible`としてもうまくいかないのですね。

元の状態（画像①）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↓
右にスクロール（画像②）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

∧∧∧∧∧  ここの100pxの部分を表示させたい。

こうしたい（画像③）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[CSS]

```
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: black;
}

.container{
    background: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    left:-100px;
    /*overflow: visible; 誤り（修正）*/
}


.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
}
```

Comment: (修正)あなたが提示されているHTML, CSSでは、.boxの要素は単にその外側の.container要素の左上に配置されるだけで、.container要素からはみ出してはいません。はみ出す部‌​分がないのだから、当然overflow:‌​visibleも効きません。あなたが画像‌​②の状態を作るために使用したHT‌​ML, CSSをお示しください。それともginさんの回答+コメントで解決の糸口がつかめたのでしょうか? その際にはコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: left:-100px;によって.containerと.boxのどちらもが、windowの左端からかくれていると思います。この状態で、ブラウザを左にスワイプする（バウンスするような状態）と、左端より右側が見えてくると思いますが、この時に、隠れるのでなく表示されている状態にしたいのです。windowの右端や下端でははみ出た部分が表示されます。左端と上端では隠れてしまいます。

Comment: バウンススクロールのように、本来はスクロールできない要素を限定的にドラッグして引っ張れるようにする機能は、特定ブラウザだけで動くもので、HTML,CSSではそのような動作の際のレンダリング方法等は規定されていません。特定のブラウザだけでできる操作ではなく、一般のHTML,CSSで規定されている動作をさせているはずだと思われるのであれば、もう少し情報をいただかないとわからないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どのブラウザでも同じことが起こるのかと思っておりまして、それを治す方法が何かあるのかと思っておりました。ちなみにこのブラウザはchromeです。

Comment: とりあえず別ブラウザで動作が再現できるかは確認して見られると良いと思います。FireFox, IE/Edge, Safariなどの他ブラウザでも動作が再現できれば、私が方法を思いつかないだけで何かHTML,CSSの範囲で取れる対策をご存知の方がいるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます！

Answer (score 1):

こういう感じのをやりたいんでしょうか？

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: black;
}

.container{
    background: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    /* left:-100px; 削除 */
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: 100px; /* 追加 */
}


.box{
    position: absolute; /* 追加 */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    left:-100px; /* 追加 */
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！あくまで何もしない時は元の状態（画像①）のような状態になっていて、画面をスクロールすると、隠れていた赤い部分が表示されるというようにしたいです。

Comment: スクロールの意味が分かりません。右(→)にスクロールすれば赤い部分は左端に消えて行ってしまいます。左に隙間が空くことはないですよね？

Comment: よく分かりませんけど「.container」に追加した「margin-left: 100px;」を消せば望み通りな形になるってことですかね？